# Do my stats on a previous console generation carry over to the next generation via Battlelog?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

A while back I purchased Battlefield 4 Premium Edition on the Xbox 360.  I put a number of hours into the multiplayer, and have made a lot of progress on many assignments.

I wish to pick up the game on the Xbox One.  I found that because I already own the Premium Edition on the Xbox 360 I am entitled to a free upgrade to the Premium Edition on the Xbox One edition.

Do my online stats also carry over?  For example, ranking and assignment progress.

If the stats do carry over, is this a one time upgrade?  Or do both console contribute to the same stats?

I am using the same Xbox live profile on both consoles.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [battlefield.com upgrade offer](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/next-gen-upgrade), **yes**:

> **When I upgrade platforms, will my stats transfer with me?**
>
> Yes! You will be able to bring your multiplayer progress with you – your rank, score, K/D ratio, wins, time played, service stars, dog tags taken, vehicles destroyed, repairs, revives, squad score, accuracy, and more will transfer from Xbox 360 to Xbox One and PlayStation 3 to PlayStation 4.

It appears to be a [one-time transfer](http://news.xbox.com/2013/08/14/games-battlefield-4-stats/), though:

[image: one time transfer]

Comment: Seems to be a one time only transfer, going by the information.  I will give it a try over the weekend.  RE: one time only - I was mainly worried about online populations.  In Call of Duty Ghosts I play the DLC on the 360 because the DLC population is very low on the One version.